# How to implement a variant of convolution operation using low-level pytorch APIs?

Tags: python, c++, pytorch, convolution

My target is to implement a variant of convolution operation in pytorch which requires high inference speed.

I have implemented one in C++ and CUDA through pytorch CPP extension. However, the speed is not satisfactory, I guess I’ll have to implement it with lower level APIs. It seems `aten/src/ATen/native/Convolution.cpp` is the right place to do so, and it further calls `aten/src/THNN/generic/SpatialConvolutionMM.c`, so I modify `SpatialConvolutionMM.c`. The problem is after compiling, I cannot see any changes on the outputs. Maybe the files in THNN are wrapped in `ATen/native` in some way, I just cannot figure it out. Could anyone give me some suggestions? Thank you.